# Match prices using regular expression, but with exceptions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a string:

```
foo bar $ 123.456 bar foo $ 652 $ 1.255.250 bar $ 2.000 foo badword $ 300.000 foo bar $ 123 badword2 $ 400
```

And I want to match all the prices, except the ones which follows a "badword".

Match:

```
123.456
652
1.255.250
2.000
123
```

Do not match:

```
badword $ 300.000
badword2 $ 400
```

I'm developing in Python 3.6 and using `(\d+).(\d+)` to capture the prices so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `(\d+).(\d+)` will capture one or more digits in capture group 1 and group 2 and the dot would match any character. That would also match `123a456`

One option to capture the prices is to match what you do not want `(?:badword|badword2) \$ \d+(?:\.\d+)*` and then capture in a group `\$ (\d+(?:\.\d+)*)` what you do want using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

[`(?:badword|badword2) \$ \d+(?:\.\d+)*|\$ (\d+(?:\.\d+)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/NWaTNC/2)

That would match

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `badword|badword2` Match bad words
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\$` Match whitespace $ whitespace
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1 or more digits followed by (a dot and 1 or more digits) repeated 0 or more times
- `|` Or
- `\$` Match whitespace $ whitespace
- `(` Capturing group (Your digits will be in here)

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)*` Match 1 or more digits followed by (a dot and 1 or more digits) repeated 0 or more times
- `)` Close capturing group

You can extend the alternation with the badwords you want to add.

Comment: I like this approach. The only fault I see is that it would match multiple decimal parts. Why are you using `*` instead of `?`?

Comment: @BrianStephens The multiple decimal parts are being matched because the OP want to match `123.456`, `652`,  `1.255.250`.  If there would be a `?` instead of `*` then `1.255.250` would [not match](https://regex101.com/r/NWaTNC/3) anymore.

Comment: Oops - you're right. I didn't look closely enough and assumed they were decimal separators, but they're really thousands separators. Very good.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks! That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd use this more pythonic approach using list comprehension. It basically extracts the price parts (potential *words*, *price*) into groups, then removes the matches whose *word* group contains `badword`, then prints only the *price* value.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##TY3BCoMwEETvfsUSPCRtCasxHgqlH6IWbFUa0ERWoZbit9vYWuhhYffN7Ez/HO/OqmUxXe9oBKqDYIATsMY5uJYEIUSxkolOP9dKQ0h1vHIZa@0HN18sERG@f9XDUeWZQvyjW9pPX0MSRBaQL6Ra3lzXm7bmxHh2CYu9yMN82PG8ekUHNfPzMZd@V7PYCSaCnowdeTZlUeHjCSYwFkg2xlZl2/JBgGmAbVUMrBtXw5RhUYhleQM)

```
import re

s = "foo bar $ 123.456 bar foo $ 652 $ 1.255.250 bar $ 2.000 foo badword $ 300.000 foo bar $ 123 badword2 $ 400"
r = re.compile(r"([^$]+)\$\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*)")
print([x[1] for x in r.findall(s) if "badword" not in x[0]])
```

The regex used in the code above is:

```
([^$]+)\$\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*)
```

The following regular expression may also be used:

```
([^$]+)\$\s*([\d.]+)
```